# Should one give charity locally or sacrifice animal in home country?

Tags: sacrifice, eid-ul-adha, udhiyyah

I have been living in UK and as per state law, one cannot slaughter animals. Some people send money back to their counties e.g Pakistan. I saw a video of Mufti Menk saying that charity should be given to the country charities in which you reside in.

Some people become really patriotic on this subject as they would rather send money to someone who they trust and can distribute accordingly, then some people also start converting money e.g I give to charity which is doing 50£ for a portion of cow, however one relative told in Pakistan it is xxx amount which converts into 130£ but it is same portion of cow.

Should one give to charity or to siblings in Muslim county who can do the sunnah?

Comment: i live in Pakistan here a portion of cow is cost around 60£, if you want i can connect you with person / organization

Comment: The advertised share of a cow in Pakistan is around Rs 13000, which is around 60 £, however if your siblings are doing it personally they may have bought an animal which might be bigger and pricier and hence the value of the share would increase. I wouldn't recommend sending money to anyone you do not know and trust.

Comment: @UmH correct but what doesn't settle with me is the relative is an aunt of my wife who is quoting that price, I personally give my qurbani to IKCA as I trust the organization n they r quoting it 50£ so there is a big difference between 130£ and 50£, plus as recommendation, there are 3 portion of qurbani, one for poor, one for relative and one for urself? But the one I send money to give it to needy only, hence my another confusion

Comment: As I said it depends. Rs 13000 per share (one of 7 shares) is the price that many organisations and buying pools quote. They buy in bulk and and sacrifice an average or small animal and are meant to be affordable. The price of an animal in the actual market depends on its age, build, breed, looks etc. People who buy for their families will buy according to their ability and some can buy very expensive animals. So you should communicate and clarify from your relative about the matter rather than having misgivings.

Comment: those who are unable to take meet back due to any reason , usually completely donate it on the name of ALLAH , and its known as acceptable but it's totally upto ALLAH which deeds he accepts.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly assuming *udhiyah* to be a type of charity. The point of udhiyah is not giving in charity, rather the ritual of sacrifice is an act of worship in itself.

This might become clearer if you consider that you can eat the meat of sacrifice yourself whereas consuming your own wealth is not charity. Giving away the meat that 'results' from the sacrifice is prescribed, although it will not invalidate the sacrifice if you eat it all yourself or even if you throw it away. Similarly you may have heard that in ancient times the sacrifice was consumed by fire, and not given away in charity.

Arranging for the sacrifice to be made on your behalf is better than giving its worth in charity. While giving in charity will fetch its own reward and is better than doing nothing, it will not equal or be better than a sacrifice.

> #### ما عمل ابن آدم من عمل يوم النحر أحب إلى الله من إهراق الدم
>
> The son of Adam does not do any deed on the day of sacrifice that is dearer to Allah than shedding blood.
>
> <sup>— [مشكاة المصابيح](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8360/1747)</sup>